# Emberjs select box test helper

Tags: ember.js

Wring the Emberjs tests have certain helpers like `fillIn`, `click` at http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/

But is there any test helpers for elements like selectbox, checkbox, radio and file-field?

Answer (score 4):

click can do the first 3, and javascript can't automate a file field, it's a security risk.

Comment: Sure, set up a jsbin (emberjs.jsbin.com) with each item and the test framework, and i'll gladly write some tests.

Comment: n/m i found someone else's that was close enough, http://plnkr.co/edit/ODvlUOLYMxe6VPx1Zjlw?p=preview  no need to use click on select